# Creating a logical connection and calling procedures on a XML-RPC server which verifies CSRF tokens - python xmlrpclib

Tags: python, xml-rpc

I am using xmlrpclib in python to connect to a xml-rpc server that verifies csrf tokens.

```
proxy = ServerProxy("http://127.0.0.1:9091/transmission/rpc/") 
proxy.system.listMethods()
```

I am getting the following exception

```
ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for 127.0.0.1:9091/transmission/rpc/: 409 Conflict>
```

When trying to access the same xml-rpc server from a browser i get the following error message.

> Your request had an invalid session-id
>   header.
>
> To fix this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. When reading a response, get its X-Transmission-Session-Id header and
>      remember it
> 2. Add the updated header to your outgoing requests
> 3. When you get this 409 error message, resend your request with the
>      updated header
>
> This requirement has been added to
>   help prevent CSRF attacks.
>
> X-Transmission-Session-Id:
>   lhfIlFPd1W6pctlHSiS3BuNXdFr0al1qxfM4wSLvVkdh5wOu

Now, i am looking for a way to send this session-id to the server whenever i use ServerProxy object to call the remote procedures. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Transmission doesn't expose an XML-RPC service. It's a JSON-RPC service. Using xmlrpclib won't work at all.

You'll need to do exactly what the error message says... record the X-Transmission-Session-Id from the response header whenever you receive a 409 error, then re-send the request with X-Transmission-Session-Id added to the request header. One way to accomplish this is by using [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html).

Transmission's RPC service expects valid JSON in the body of the request. You can find the specification here: https://trac.transmissionbt.com/browser/trunk/extras/rpc-spec.txt